# Read a particular json value with angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I use angularjs for read a particular json value :

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: urlVersion}).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("success data " + status);
    $scope.ext = data.versions['chrome'];
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log("error data " + status);
});
```

json file is :

```
{
    "versions": {
        "android": "none",
        "chrome": "0.1"
    }
}
```

i have nothing in return and console give me no error... what's wrong ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $scope.ext = data.versions.chrome;

Comment: @Acsisr: Both is valid with JS.

@JoDiii: Does the console.log for the `"success data "` fire?

Comment: @ Acsisr : nothing in result, @ Charminbear : yes i have "success data 200"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `responseType: 'json'` to the http request and print the whole data object to console.

Comment: Object {versions: Object}
versions: Object
android: "none"
chrome: "0.1"

Answer (score 0):

To Read the value of say for example 'chrome'

### You have to read it as below

**data[0].versions['chrome'];**

---

To read the data of the json.You need to have the index of the elment.

- View the JSON :To get the view of the json : http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/
- Validate the JSON:To validate the JSON structure is correct or not : http://jsonlint.com/